# Running Multiple PDO Statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am learning the in's and out's of PHP's PDO for MySQL. My question is, if I have to run multiple different MySQL statements per execution, do I need to define `$pdo = new PDO(...);` before each new (different) statement?

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT userid, email FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password');
$sql->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email'], ':password' => md5($_POST['password'])));
$result = $sql->fetchObject();

$sql = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET access_count = access_count + 1, timestamp_last_access = :timestamp WHERE userid = :userid');
$sql->execute(array(':timestamp' => TIMESTAMP, ':user_id' => $result->user_id));
$result = $sql->fetchObject();
```

Do I need to call a new instance of `$pdo = new PDO(...);` or can I keep it open through the full execution of the script?

Comment: What's keeping you from just spending 30 seconds on testing it yourself?

Comment: I am wondering what is more efficient, I know it works, but is it recommended/efficient?

Comment: If it's a question of best practices, then ask it as one. As the answers below demonstrate, nobody is saying anything about what's recommended or more efficient, simply because that's not your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PDO is just another class in PHP. Here is a simple example to demonstrate one instance...

```
class Test {
    private $i = 0;

    public function increment() {
        $this->i++;
        return $this->i;
    }
}

$test = new Test();
echo $test->increment(); // 1
echo $test->increment(); // 2
echo $test->increment(); // 3
```

Comment: Could be shortened to `return ++$this->i;`. Just sayin' :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create another instance of it :)

You should give this a read:- [OOP: The Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)